# How to determine amount of memory used by different solr caches

Tags: caching, memory, solr, solr4

According to Solr wiki https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrCaching

> **filterCach**e stores unordered sets of document IDs that match the key
>
> **queryResultCache** stores ordered sets of document IDs

What is the document id being referred to here? What is its size? Is it a boolean bit vector with 1/0 for all documents present in the collection, such that its size is equivalent to total docs * 1 bit?

Also is there any way to get the exact size of each cache in bytes?